# Python3: Creating a string with an unescaped backslash

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, escaping

In Python 3.3, I am trying to rebuild unicode characters from truncated unicode values,
and then print the character to console.

For example, from '4E00' I want to form the string '\u4E00'. I have tried:

```
base = '4E00'
uni = r'\u' + base
print(uni)      # getting '\u4E00', want: '一'
print(repr(uni))    # '\\u4E00'
```

Is there a way to form an unescaped string like '\u4E00' in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
chr(int(base, 16))
```

to turn a hex value into a Unicode character.

The `\u` escape sequence only works in string literals. You *could* use:

```
(br'\u' + base.encode('ascii')).decode('unicode_escape')
```

but that's much more verbose than this needs to be.

Demo:

```
>>> base = '4E00'
>>> chr(int(base, 16))
'一'
>>> (br'\u' + base.encode('ascii')).decode('unicode_escape')
'一'
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that `\u` followed by a Unicode character code is only a thing in string literals. `r'\u' + '4E00'` has no special meaning as a Unicode character because it's not all in one literal; it's just a six-character string.

So you're trying to take a Unicode escape code as it would appear in a Python string literal, then decode that into a Unicode character. You can do that:

```
base = '4E00'
uni = str(bytes(r'\u' + base, encoding="ascii"), encoding="unicode_escape")
```

But it's the long way around (especially since you have to convert it to `bytes` first since it's already Unicode). Your Unicode character spec is in hexadecimal. So convert it directly to an integer and then use `chr()` to turn it into a Unicode character.

```
base = '4E00'
uni = chr(int(base, 16))
```